# How do I Display jsp source code in a jsp page

Tags: jsp, syntaxhighlighter

I am writing documentation for a company widget i authored and would like to run it on our development site but i need to show some jsp source code in the page.

How do i stop code from being interpolated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;`.

You can if necessary make it a bean property and use JSTL `<c:out>` to display it. It by defaut does that job.